# Datagridview Row painting every other block of 4 rows

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

So instead of alternating every other row, I need to to alternate every other 4 rows. so a 1-4 would be blue and 5-8 would be white. I've tried to use mod and the `rowindex` but I keep messing up and not finding the correct way to do it, I then noticed that the data that the grid is pulling in has a column that has the same number every 4 rows. so I was thinking I can compare that value and when it changes I know that I have to change the color scheme and go for another 3 rows then switch back. below is code used and screen shot sample. it will just paint the whole grid one color.

```
Private Sub BTFDataGrid_RowPrePaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles BTFDataGrid.RowPrePaint
    Dim i, ReelNum,Count As Integer
    ReelNum = BTFDataGrid.Rows(0).Cells("ReelNumber").Value    

    For i = 1 To BTFDataGrid.Rows.Count-1
        If ReelNum = BTFDataGrid.Rows(e.Rowindex).Cells("ReelNumber").Value Then
            BTFDataGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
        Else
            BTFDataGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
            Count = Count + 1
            If Count = 4 Then
                ReelNum = BTFDataGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("ReelNumber").Value 
                Count = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ' This is using index
    'Dim dgv = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
    'Dim colorIndex As Integer = If((e.RowIndex / rowStep) Mod 2 = 0, 0, 1)
    'dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = rowColors(colorIndex)

    'For Each row As DataGridViewRow In BTFDataGrid.Rows
    '    Dim colorIndex As Integer = If((row.Index / rowStep) Mod 2 = 0, 0, 1)
    '    BTFDataGrid.Rows(row.Index).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = rowColors(colorIndex)
    'Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What should happen if the grid is sorted diffrerently?

Comment: wil always be lowest down to highest. or highest to lowest, and in block form like this

Comment: It looks like you're doing every row, for each event. Do you want that? You have `BTFDataGrid.RowPrePaint` with `For i = 1 To BTFDataGrid.Rows.Count-1`

Comment: So each event is triggered on every row?  i dont want that. that like a double loop right? all i want really is to have rows 1-4 to be a certain color and then 5-8 another color and then 9-12 to be back to the same color as 1-4 so on and so forth. alternating but in blocks of 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This meets your needs I think:

```
Private Sub BTFDataGrid_RowPrePaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles BTFDataGrid.RowPrePaint
    DirectCast(sender, DataGridView).Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = If((e.RowIndex \ 4) Mod 2 = 0, Color.LightBlue, Color.WhiteSmoke)
End Sub
```

Comment: this was short and sweet, did exactly what i needed. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Field to define the List/Array of Colors used to paint the DataGridView Rows and a Field that defines an Interval: the number of consecutive Rows that use the same Color in the list of Colors.

The Index of the Color in the List of Colors is then:

```
[Color Index] = ([Row Index] \ [Interval]) Mod [Number of Colors]
```

This way, you can also add more Colors to the List/Array and color the Rows with more than two Colors, alternating all the Colors with the specified Interval.

You can use the `RowPrePaint` or `RowPostPaint` event handlers to define the Color to use as the background color of the Row at current index (specified by `e.RowIndex`):

```
' To alternate more than two colors, add them to the array, e.g.
' Private rowColors As Color() = {Color.LightBlue, Color.White, Color.LightGreen}
Private rowColors As Color() = {Color.LightBlue, Color.White}
Private rowsInterval As Integer = 4

Private Sub BTFDataGrid_RowPrePaint(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs) Handles BTFDataGrid.RowPrePaint
    Dim colorIndex = (e.RowIndex \ rowsInterval) Mod rowColors.Length
    BTFDataGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = rowColors(colorIndex)
End Sub
```

As a note, you could paint the Row's background instead of setting the `BackColor` of the Row's DefaultCellStyle.

Comment: thanks jimi, this was exactly what steveCinq also posted about this one. just less code same concept. i appreciate the time you took to make this

Answer (score 0):

This answer is more generic, for general purpose

Do something every 4th count

```vb
For i as integer = 0 To someCount
    If  (i + 1) Mod 4 = 0 Then
        ' Do something every 4th item
    End If
Next
```

Do something for groups of defined size

```vb
dim groupSize as integer = 4
dim cycle as integer = 0

For i as integer = 0 To someCount
    if cycle = groupSize then
        ' change color
         Console.WriteLine("---------------------")
         cycle = 0
    end if
        
    Console.WriteLine(i)
    cycle += 1
        
Next
```

Comment: will this just do something to the 4th item or will it do it to the next 3 also after the 4th item? because supposed to do as a block of 4.

Comment: i test that, and it does just as you said only the 4th row, what i need is to paint the first  4 rows (block) one color and then then following 4 rows another color, alternating colors by blocks of 4.

Comment: steve had posted the missing part, the division of the row by the interval modded by 2. thank you for the time you took to help.